# How do I make my iOS application resize correctly to all iphone devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mobile, mobile-development

I have created my iOS application using Xcode but it works fine with iPhone 6 , but when I try to simulate in any other device the UI gets misaligned. How do I make the application to fit correctly to all the iPhone devices ?

Comment: I am a begineer in iOS development, can you please elaborate the answer ?

Comment: If You found any of the answers in this topic helpful, then please upvote or accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these links [Autolayout](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/) or [Autolayout programatically](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/)

[developer.apple.Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: @RizwanAhmed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oMBJuzanws

Comment: Thank you once again I was thinking to ask about any video tutorials and you gave it.

Comment: It is not working I tried by setting constraints and all. It is not working.

Comment: follow this tutorial [building-adaptive-user-interfaces-ios-8](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-adaptive-user-interfaces-ios-8/)
And 
http://www.brianjcoleman.com/autolayout-xcode6/

Comment: I tried everything as said in the tutorial, but it is not getting aligned properly. I don't know where I am going wrong. Please help anyone.

Comment: can you please give me image of layout?

Comment: Here is the screenshot of constraints which are added, the code and the sample in the simulator (I had used iPhone 4S for simulating)

http://i.imgur.com/F33JRTH.png

Comment: there are two buttons: play, how to play, about the game And one label welcome to guess me. but give me final out-put image which you need buddy. :)

Comment: On the left hand side I had show you a screen right in the design mode. I want an interface like that. Can you help ?

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DK9LU.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1EBRN.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nIclR.png
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7DRHt.png

Output:
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv5QA.png
This might helps you :)

Comment: Thank you so much yuyutsu, It worked but only a small issue, the buttons or labels sometimes become as three dots (...) what do I do for that ? I tried everything by resizing it , changing the width and height , etc. What to do now ?

Comment: Finally I was able to solve all the problems thank you Yuyutsu, but a small and last problem, when the orientation of the device gets changed , it gets disorted. Screenshots: 1. http://i.imgur.com/kIxjvDs.png  2. http://i.imgur.com/5fRyDVH.png

Comment: can I tell you tomorrow please? Thanks :)

Comment: Update - I some how managed to make the constraints proper but, now the problem is with the navigation bar in the landscape view. When I add a navigation bar this error occurs. I m really sorry to annoy you buddy :( I'm just a begineer :(  Screenshot: 1. http://imgur.com/nSEC188,lQv647X,yVvQT8e#1
2.http://imgur.com/nSEC188,lQv647X,yVvQT8e#0
3.http://imgur.com/nSEC188,lQv647X,yVvQT8e#2

the problem is with the third screenshot.

Comment: can you please send me the code? I'll update it and send you back. if possible :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply here are the project files https://www.mediafire.com/?i2yqezbpd1ceuma

Comment: Hello, @RizwanAhmed, can you please do one things 1: remove segue of  `PlayGameViewController` 2: remove navigation of `PlayGameViewController ` 3: add segue show to the play button. your problem will be solved

Comment: @RizwanAhmed, If you really want to learn `Auto-layout` the please read carefully above blog. Its really helps you :)

Comment: That really solved the problem :) Thank you so much Yuyutsu. I will definitely follow your advice. Do you have any contact website or id so that  in case of any doubts I can contact you ?

Comment: Update : I uploaded my app to app store and they rejected it and they have mentioned that the UI was complex. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should check autolayout. If You google it You should get A LOT of examples and tutorials, here is one of ma favourites: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1